# Rename images after they're scanned - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to do a Python3 program that rename the files in a sequential order immediatly after they're scanned.

For example: The Scanner create the files named Scan_001.jpg, Scan_002.jpg and so on, and then, if i remove one of the .jpg files, the the scanner will restart the Counter. I don't need that.

What i want to do, is rename the scanner files to a sequential order, regardless what the file name is, the sequence must continue to a crescent order and never restart the counter.

something like:

```
counter = 0
if newfile 
    rename newfilefile.jpg to file_counter.jpg
    counter++
end
```

that's the logic i want to follow, but in Python3 and it must save the counter for the future scanned files.

Sorry, english isn't my mother language.

Thank's for the help guys!

Edit: I made this simple script.

```
import os, time
os.rename('teste', time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.jpg"))
```

Now, i need to automate this code to run on each Scan_xxx.jpg file each time that the scanner generate the file.

**Solution:** I made the script run on the Windows Task Scheduler every 1 minute. It's not the appropriate but it is doing his job.

Comment: If you rename a file, you essentially remove the old file(name). Which, accordingly to your second paragraph, will restart the counter on the scanner. So you would always end up with a Scan_001.jpg file coming from the scanner; is that correct?

Comment: Btw, why rename them promptly if the scanner already creates sequentially numbered images for you anyway? Why not do it after the scanning?

Comment: @Evert Yes, i will end up always with a Scan_001.jpg file, but i use the scanner frequently, and, sometimes i will organize the .jpg files on their respective folder, i ocasionally end up with a conflict with the file names.